# How to set Mutliple Conutries restriction in AutocompleteFilter class Google API?

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, autocompletefilter

I am using this dependency on my project:

```
compile'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.1'
```

I want to show autocomplete for only two countries (USA & Mexico):

I tried this code but it does not work for multiple countries. Whens I use this code it shows Mexico result.

```
AutocompleteFilter filter =
new AutocompleteFilter.Builder().setCountry("US").setCountry("MX").build();
```

I tried to google it but I didn't find the answer. SetConutry only has single string parameter.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: not sure but have you tried with .setCountry("US, MX")

Comment: yes but it doesn't works @Pravin